# Delegates - What's the difference between Add() and AddUObject()?

Tags: c++, delegates, unreal-engine4

When binding a Multi Cast Delegate, what is the use differences between `Add()` and `AddUObject()`?

I've been using `AddUObject()` on all of my bindings and they seems to work fine which has me wondering what the base `Add()` version is used for.

Ive read the information on this page :

[Unreal Documentation - Multicast Delegates](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Multicast/)

But I'm not quite sure the appropriate place to use each one. In what scenario would I use `Add()` or `AddUObject()`?

Thanks!

Comment: If it’s a “weak delegate”, I might expect the bound delegate to *not* keep the target object alive. I suspect this avoids having the always meticulously remove delegates to avoid memory “leaks”.

Comment: Also looks like `AddUObject`will check the object is alive before executing the callback. Not sure about `Add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Add` takes in an `FDelegate`.

`AddUObject` is syntactic sugar for creating a templated delegate and binding it to the provided UObject, then calling `Add` with the created delegate.

It is just this:

```
template <typename UserClass, typename... VarTypes>
inline FDelegateHandle AddUObject(const UserClass* InUserObject, typename TMemFunPtrType<true, UserClass, void (ParamTypes..., VarTypes...)>::Type InFunc, VarTypes... Vars)
{
    return Add(FDelegate::CreateUObject(InUserObject, InFunc, Vars...));
}
```